# Finding Semi-direct products of Z/3Z and Z/7Z

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

This problem originated from trying to find the group isomorphisms of groups of order 21. I already worked out that there's one subgroup of order 7 that's normal, and one subgroup of order 3. Even though 7 ≡ 1(mod 3), by simple counting I worked out that there can't be seven groups of order 3 and one of order 7.

Let the Sylow 7 subgroup be N, and let the Sylow 3 subgroup be H. I then considered the semi-direct product of N and H, and the function  f:H→Aut(N). I know I can do this because |H||N|=21, N is normal, and H ∩ N = {e}, since all elements of H have different orders to all elements of N.

Let H= < a >, N= < b >. There's obviously the trivial map when 1,a,and a^2 go to e, and then a mapping where f(a)=b^2 and f(a^2)=b^4. But what about the mapping where f(a)=b^4 and f(a^2)=b^2? Are these two mappings different?

And I'm pretty new here, so could anyone also tell me how to properly type out the powers of numbers instead of just using ^? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: How can't there by seven subgroups of order $3$? If the group is not cyclic, there are no elements of order $21$. The single subgroup of order $7$ contains the identity and six elements of order $7$. There are fourteen other elements whose order can only be $3$ and you need seven subgroups of order $3$ to fit them in.

Comment: Oh, right, my mental arithmetic was wrong. For some reason I thought that there would be 18 elements of order 3. Thanks for that.